# В каких случаях msi возвращает exit code 3010/1641?

Tags: развертывание, windowsinstaller, msi

Известно, что Windows Installer возвращает 3010 или 1641 если после установки нужна перезагрузка. Вопрос в том, в каких случаях они возвращаются? Это устанавливается какими-то публичными свойствами или же после каких-то действий с сервисами/определенными местами в реестре/определенными местами в файловой системе? Везде есть только информация, что это за коды, а информацию, когда они возвращаются, нигде не могу найти.

Answer (score 1):

Стандартные экшены ForceReboot и ScheduleReboot делают это:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/reboot